# Multithreaded C++ program using 30% CPU in Windows (compiled with MinGW), but 100% in Linux

Tags: c++, gtk, mingw, glib, msys

I have written a C++ program for solving a difficult optimization problem using multiple processors. Its basic structure can be seen in the snippet below. The paralellization is made in a simple way using glib, by spawning threads with `g_thread_new`.

The program was originally developed in Linux, where htop shows that it uses 100% of all cores. But in Windows the CPU usage peaks at around 30-40% in a quad-core computer with 4 processors + 4 virtual processors. I have compiled it in Windows using `MinGW` and `g++`.

Why is the performance so degraded under Windows? Is this caused by the fact that I compiled the program using MinGW?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void intensive_function() {
    //... heavy computations
    return;
}

static gpointer worker(gpointer data) {
    intensive_function();
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int processors = thread::hardware_concurrency();

    for(int i = 0; i < processors; i++) {
        GThread *thread;
        thread = g_thread_new("worker", worker, NULL);
        g_thread_unref(thread);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `::std::thread` and Visual C++ on Windows?

Comment: I am trying to compile using the same Makefile that I use on Linux, and MinGW allows that. Is Visual C++ expected to perform better? I will look up std::thread.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

Try to check value:

int processors = thread::hardware_concurrency();

the value can be other than processors/cores amount.

Comment: In Windows, this is highly unlikely. If it does return 1 then it is a compiler problem.